# Windows Server Backup Problems

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, hyper-v, windows-sbs-2008, windows-server-backup

I've got a bit of a problem here that I have inherited. Currently, I have two Windows 2012 servers running.

- One server is a production server with 1 Hyper-V VM on it that has SBS 2008 on the guest VM.
- The other server is a standby server just in case the other server goes down, we can restore the production server to the stand by server.

**On the production server:**

There are 3 disks with two drives `C:` and `D:` on separate disks and a third disk that has an unformatted disk.

Windows Server Backup has been backing up to the standby server via UNC path. The backup gets stored put on a physical drive and then every night gets copied to an external drive to have a weeks worth of backups.

We had an issue a couple of days ago that an employee had deleted some info from a spreadsheet that we needed to recover. I went into Windows Server Backup and noticed that I could only recover the previous days backup from the calendar. Unfortunately, every time I try to view the files, restore vms or anything like that, it says that windows backup cannot find the backup set media.

Ever since I tried to recover the files, the backups are now failing. I am getting this error:

```
The backup operation that started at
'‎2015‎-‎11‎-‎04T03:00:03.384015500Z' has failed with following error
code '0x8078014B' (There was a failure in creating a directory on the
backup storage location.). Please review the event details for a
solution, and then rerun the backup operation once the issue is
resolved.
```

I saw a couple of posts that say that it was a permissions issue but the directory permissions are set to everyone. So, I don't think it is that.

What can we do to fix this and what can we do to make the process better?

Best Regards, Edward Rhoades II

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2009/04/13/customizing-windows-server-backup-schedule.aspx

"You can use a network location (i.e. \servername\foldername) as a backup target in above commands. However, **network backups will save only the latest version of the backup, deleting the previous version, as multiple versions on the network share are not supported.**"

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problems and solved them this way:

1. The Daily backups are done using [Image for Windows](http://www.terabyteunlimited.com/image-for-windows.htm);
   it costs about $39(!) per Server, works perfectly with Servers, support incremental backups and supports bare metal restore, too. (disclaimer: we're just happy users)
   The GUI allows to create a command-line, which we copied to scheduled task.
   We also use their script [IFWRotate](http://www.terabyteunlimited.com/downloads/ifwrotateoncount.zip) which allows automatic deletion of old backups.
   Additionally, they answer customers questions :-)
2. We allow users to restore their lost files itself by using Windows the built in function ShadowCopyVolume. We created a scheduled task on the server which hosts the files:
   Command line: C:\Windows\system32\vssadmin.exe
   Arguments: Create Shadow /AutoRetry=15 /For=\?\Volume{ecd8b3c1-e9e2-4af3-8ed0-d0749656bd59}\
   Start in: %systemroot%\system32
   Trigger: Every Day at 07:00 and at 12:00

Solution 2 creates two volume snapshots each day. Users can open the folder / file property dialog and select the "Previous Versions" register and then browse and restore the backed up files.

Kind regards,
Tom